# PC Using LLVMPIPE Instead of Matrox GPU

Tags: gpu, matrox

I have been making using of my pc for a while and had bad display. thought it was my monitor so I decided to change it. but later figured out that my system is making use of Llvmpipe instead of the Matrox. How can I rectify this issue?

running on matrox g200, failed to find any drivers to install.
ubuntu 20.2

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. There is not enough information in your question to offer a clear answer. Have you installed the necessary drivers for your graphics card? If so, could you [edit] your question to include: (0) which version of Ubuntu you’re running (1) which Matrox card you’re using (2) which driver is installed. With this, it may be possible to offer a potential solution or narrow down the issue 

Comment: *Matrox* in 2023?

Comment: it came with my system

Comment: Must be very old hardware. The stock kernel of Ubuntu 17.04 is doing away with Direct Rendering Manager (DRM) support for a number of ancient graphics processors.
3Dfx Banshee/Voodoo3+, ATI Rage 128, Matrox G200/G400, SIS, VIA, and Savage hardware

Comment: the driver you need is mgag200 and it is part of the mainline Linux kernel.  It's supposed to work nicely with Wayland but apparently it wasn't necessarily doing so until more recently, so try switching to xorg and see if it works properly.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231887/20-04-lts-boot-hang-matrox-g200ew-after-successful-install

Comment: actually you may need to install the driver manually, it's `xserver-xorg-video-mga`. You would then have to disable Wayland and possibly blacklist the `mgag200` kernel module.

Comment: whenever I install `xserver-xorg-video-mga` and reboot the system fails to boot correctly and then leaving a blank page with the cursor blinking. although I haven't tried blacklist mgag200.

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 20.2